# Check if REQUEST_URI Does not contain a string

Tags: mod-rewrite, request-uri

Our current setup redirects to a specific page if the requested file is pdf,xls,etc

Now we want to add an exception to the rule to exclude files prepended with some specific text such as "FSP_"

But my exceptions are not working.
It works if I allow it to redirect if the text is present, but not when I negate it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(pdf|doc|xlsx|docx|xls)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/FSP_
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/permissions/
```

If I remove the ! then it does the opposite of what I want - It redirects anything with the prefix

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have reviewed several references on the issue but still unable to get this working

[htaccess redirect if url doesn't contain some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669761/htaccess-redirect-if-url-doesnt-contain-some-string)

[htaccess RewriteCond REQUEST_URI detection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089392/htaccess-rewritecond-request-uri-detection-not-working)

[RewriteCond REQUEST_URI - ^ doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465842/rewritecond-request-uri-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Looked up the Apache pages as well but still not closer.